# Shuffle/permute values within specific columns, for a specific factor level of group-variable

Tags: r, permutation, sample, r-factor

I have a dataframe like the one below. I would like to mix up the the values from columns V1,V2 and V3 within factor levels A1,A2,B1,B2.

```
n<-1:10
df <- data.frame(factor = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2",
                             "B1","B1","B1","B2","B2","B2"),                     
                vars<-as.data.frame(sapply(1:3,function(i)sample(n,12,replace=T))) )

   factor V1 V2 V3
1      A1  8  1  1
2      A1  7  2  9
3      A1  4  5  2
4      A2  6  5  2
5      A2  8  3  4
6      A2  1  9  3
7      B1  5  6  8
8      B1 10  4  6
9      B1  6  1  9
10     B2  4  6  7
11     B2  7  5  8
12     B2 10  2  7
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
   factor V1 V2 V3
1      A1  4  1  2
2      A1  8  5  1
3      A1  7  2  9
4      A2  8  9  2
5      A2  1  3  3
6      A2  6  5  4
7      B1  5  4  6
8      B1  6  6  8
9      B1  10 1  9
10     B2  10 6  8
11     B2  4  2  7
12     B2  7  5  7
```

I would ideally like to change the columns within the dataframe - not to add columns onto it. I have tried different options I found on this page such as:

```
require(plyr)
df1<- ddply(df, .(factor),summarize, ans=sample(V1))
or
df2<-transform(df, new.V1=ave(c(V1), factor, FUN=function(b) sample(b)))
```

Both work fine for just changing one column, but in both cases I cannot get it to sample several columns at once. df1 generates a new column without the rest of the old dataframe and df2 attaches the sampled column onto the old one. So in a way I prefer df1, but that doesn't help if I can't get it do several columns at once. There must be a simple solution to this, but I have scanned up and down stackoverflow and can't seem to find a solution. I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: I don't get why you title this *"Permute/sample columns only within factor levels"*. You mean *"Shuffle/permute values within specific columns, for a specific factor level of group-variable"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have the approach down--you just need to figure out how to apply it across multiple columns. For this, I would suggest `lapply`, like this...

First, your sample data (but reproducible, with `set.seed`)

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 1:10
df <- data.frame(factor = c("A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2",
                            "B1","B1","B1","B2","B2","B2"),
                 vars <- as.data.frame(
                   sapply(1:3, function(i) 
                     sample(n, 12, replace = T))))
df
#    factor V1 V2 V3
# 1      A1  3  7  3
# 2      A1  4  4  4
# 3      A1  6  8  1
# 4      A2 10  5  4
# 5      A2  3  8  9
# 6      A2  9 10  4
# 7      B1 10  4  5
# 8      B1  7  8  6
# 9      B1  7 10  5
# 10     B2  1  3  2
# 11     B2  3  7  9
# 12     B2  2  2  7
```

We'll work on a copy instead of directly modifying your original data.

```
df_copy <- df ## Because the next step is destructive

df_copy[-1] <- lapply(df_copy[-1], function(x) {
  ave(x, df_copy[[1]], FUN = sample)
})
df_copy
#    factor V1 V2 V3
# 1      A1  6  8  1
# 2      A1  3  4  3
# 3      A1  4  7  4
# 4      A2  3 10  4
# 5      A2  9  5  9
# 6      A2 10  8  4
# 7      B1  7  4  6
# 8      B1  7 10  5
# 9      B1 10  8  5
# 10     B2  2  7  7
# 11     B2  1  2  2
# 12     B2  3  3  9
```

Comment: Does df_copy[[1]] refer to the first column (factor) after which my data should be sorted? I am asking because in my actual dataframe I have more than the one factor column, so I would need to select the one that I want to sample my variables within.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the permute package for this. It allows a variety of permutation designs:

```
require(permute)
CTRL <- how(plots = Plots(strata = df$factor))
apply(df[, 2:4], 2, function(x)
  x[shuffle(length(x), control = CTRL)]
  )
```

I used apply, as you want to shuffle the columns independently.

Comment: that works great, thanks. However, is there a way of including the factor in the output aswell, so I can make sure to attach it (cbind or merge) it correctly to the rest of the dataframe (with many other explanatory variables)?